# Auto Adjust subviews in a UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimation

I have no.of subviews added in the UIView, at runtime I am changing the frame(increasing) of the UIView with the basic UIAnimations.
But the subviews which I have added are not proportionately increasing/decreasing with the super view. In the interface builder I have adjusted the Auto Sizing mask for all the subviews to get adjusted according to the parent/super view.But it didnt worked.Can anyone help me in this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the view you resize has ***autoresizesSubviews*** property set to YES